# How do we group continuous date into single date span in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

Here is my data:

| id | customercode | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | 20200812 | 20200814 |
| 2 | 122 | 20200816 | 20200817 |
| 3 | 122 | 20200817 | 20200819 |
| 4 | 122 | 20200821 | 20200822 |
| 5 | 122 | 20200823 | 20200824 |

I tried the following code:

```
select Customercode, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate       
from (      
      select Customercode,  startdate, enddate      
             sum(rst) over (order by Customercode, DOS) as grp      
      from (        
             select Customercode, startdate, enddate        
                    case when coalesce(lag(enddate) over (partition by Customercode order by Customercode, startdate), startdate) + 1 <> startdate then 1 end rst       
             from   tbl     
           ) t1     
     ) t2       
group by grp, Customercode      
order by startdate
```

My result

| id | customercode | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | 20200812 | 20200814 |
| 2 | 122 | 20200816 | 20200817 |
| 3 | 122 | 20200817 | 20200819 |
| 4 | 122 | 20200821 | 20200824 |

The desired output should be like this.  Please share your thoughts.

| id | customercode | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | 20200812 | 20200814 |
| 2 | 122 | 20200816 | 20200819 |
| 3 | 122 | 20200821 | 20200824 |

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag only one database.

Comment: Do you want to group records where the start date is the same as the previous end date, or 1 day afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you want to group records whose start date is the same as the previous end date, or one day afterwards.

If you want group on the same date, you would phrase the query as:

```
select customercode, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when startdate = lag_enddate then 0 else 1 end)    
            over(partition by customercode order by startdate) as grp
    from (
        select t.*,
            lag(enddate) over(partition by customercode order by startdate) as lag_enddate
        from tbl t
    ) t
) t
group by customercode, grp
order by min(startdate)
```

You can also allow both cases at once, by modifying the conditional window `sum()`. This requires a little date artithmetics, whose syntax varies across databases. In standard SQL:

```
        sum(case when startdate <= lag_enddate + interval '1' day then 0 else 1 end)    
            over(partition by customercode order by startdate) as grp
```

Comment: @Anjaly did this answer your question?